# Confused about encrypted EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and wondering how to check if my volume is encrypted.

I have an instance with an unencrypted root volume and I'd like to mount an encrypted volume. I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) to mount the drive, but how can I check if it's encrypted? From the terminal it looks like a normal folder. Will everything that gets saved to the mount point (i.e. `/data`) be encrypted? Thanks.

Comment: Does the AWS console show the EBS volume as encrypted?

Comment: Yes -- it just doesn't look any different when I access it from SSH.. is the encryption/decryption behind the scenes that I'm just not aware of..? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, encryption is transparent to the EC2 instance. It happens at the storage layer and does not impact how the volume is used on the instance.

Comment: I have the same problem except the instance I attached the encrypted volume to has a role thats not allowed in the keys policy.. how am I still able to access the data as if it is unencrypted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AWS console will show you if an EBS volume is encrypted or not. You can also use the awscli.

EBS encryption occurs on the servers that host EC2 instances, encrypting data in transit from EC2 instances to EBS storage. EBS volumes are encrypted at rest, as are snapshots and all disk i/o.

You do not see any of this from within an SSH session. The data is encrypted/decrypted automatically.

See [Amazon EBS Encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSEncryption.html) for more details.